# Why position: relative; places background elements their existent on front?

Tags: css

```
.main-column h2 {
    padding-top: 110px;
    padding-bottom: 110px;
    background: url('someimagehere.png') no-repeat center top;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative; /*so that the image stays on top.*/
}

.text-column {
    width: 215px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-top: -120px; /*so that it enters inside the h2*/
    padding-top: 120px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

<div class="main-column">
 <h2>Hello tittle 1</h2>
  <div class="text-column">
   <p>I'm on column 1 and I like it</p>
   <p>I'm on column 1 as well</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works, but I don't get it.

Why does given "position: relative" to the h2, will place the background image there visible, on top of the other element yellow background color?

Again, this code works. I'm just asking for help on understanding the behavior.

Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using position:relative or position:absolute or position:fixed allows you to also use a z-index value to determine the order of stacking.

if you set z-index:-1 on the h2 it should push it back behind the other elements. Alternatively you could set position:relative on the other element and set a higher z-index on that.

Comment: What I don't understand is why that's the case. Why does a relative position element with NO z-index declared, stays on top of the default static one?

Comment: When you create an element with position:relative, it defaults to z-index:0. That is relative to the parent element. Elements with z-index no-longer matter what order they appear in the markup, so since your H2 is the only element with position:relative and a z-index in the div, it will appear on top

Comment: That seems logical enough for me to understand it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> **Stacking without z-index**
>
> When no element has a z-index, elements are stacked in this order
>   (from bottom to top):
>
> - Background and borders of the root element
> - Descendant blocks in the normal flow, in order of appearance (in HTML)
> - Descendant positioned elements, in order of appearance (in HTML)

Read [the full article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FUnderstanding_z-index%2FStacking_without_z-index) ([and the other six articles eplaining Z-Index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FUnderstanding_z-index)) at MDN.

By enabling WebGL, you can also watch the page in 3D to debug: 
with **FireFox**, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> , then click on the Cube icon on the right to view the page in 3D. Then click with mouse and drag to rotate and inspect what is happening on the z-axis.

Answer (score 0):

When you put an element to a `position:relative;` it comes over the others element, if you want it stays in background, use `z-index: -1;` on your H2

Comment: I wish NOT to fix the code. Or change it. I wish only to understand. I'm aware that it works like that. I just don't understand why does it work like that. :)